# flutter opposite required annotation

Tags: flutter, dart

what `@required` does is that it will see if the argument is passed or not and show a warning if the argument has been missed

what I want is opposite, means if the argument is missed, shows nothing and if passed, shows the argument is redundant and will be ignored.

the reason I have to do, is that I have a base class `Usecase`:

```
abstract class Usecase<F extends Failure, S, Params extends Tuple> {
  Future<Either<F, S>> call({Params param});
}
```

then in my ovverrides, in some places I need argument and in some other places, I don't need argument, so I think it's better to annotate my `Param` with `@required` in places which I have to pass argument and annotate other `Param` with a custom `Required` opposite annotation which there is no need for argument.

Comment: Uhm, why would you want to have an argument that is redundant and will be ignored in the first place?

Comment: I added the reseon, hope it clarifies the question

Comment: I think that the [`@Deprecated`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Deprecated-class.html) annotation would behave like you want, but using it would be rather misleading.  Additionally, I don't think that annotating overrides would be very useful since it wouldn't help at all for calls through the base class interface.  I'd just document the interface to indicate that implementations might ignore the argument.

Comment: oh, Thanks I am in search of something exactly the same as ```@deprecated```

Comment: but it would be awesome if I know how to implement it for further usage